# What Is The Limit On Record Count When Using Upsert in Apex?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, upsert

When using Apex in a transaction, what is the maximum number of records that can undergo the upsert command?

Example:

I am consuming a web service (SOAP) that returns me a lot of information. I convert this String into a List  and I have a total of 1800 records. When I run the command upsert this list, the records are not updated and I get no error message.

Comment: What is being upserted? Is it a custom or standard object?

Answer (score 2):

From [Understanding Execution Governors and Limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) the:

> Total number of records processed as a result of DML statements,
>   Approval.process, or database.emptyRecycleBin

is 10,000.

An upsert is DML (Data Manipulation Language), so 1,800 records should not hit that limit assuming there is no dependent processing such as triggers running that in turn cause further DML.